# View creation more than once time

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am new to Backbone. We have developed some POC. 
We have one button on view. On every button click below function will be called and making server call to get the data.

**Every time we are creating new view by passing collection to the view.**
**Is this a correct way to create view more than one at one time?**

```
renderData : function(pageInfo, inputModel) {

        MySpinner.start();

        //Fetch the data

        var deferedData = Application.request("app:generateData"inputModel);
        $.when(deferedData).done(function(myCollection) {
            var myView = new MyView({
                collection : myCollection
            });
            //Display the view.
            Application.mainViewRegion.show(myView);
            Application.stop();
        });
}
```

Comment: INHO, no reason to create new view. You can create it once, pass link to collection to this view, add event listener to collection fetch and reset and re-render view on every collection update

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Marionette's  `CollectionView` and resetting its `collection` using the response?

From the [docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionview-automatic-rendering):

> When the collection for the view is "reset", the view will call render on itself and re-render the entire collection.